# How to get excluded collection without a second LINQ query?

Tags: c#

I have a LINQ query that looks like this:

```
 var p = option.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.PropertyType == typeof(bool));
```

What is the most efficient way to get the items which aren't included in this query, without executing a second iteration over the list.

I could easily do this with a `for` loop but I was wondering if there's a shorthand with LINQ.

Comment: A for loop is an iteration too.

Comment: `var p2 = option.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t != typeof(bool));` or `var p2 = option.GetType().GetProperties().Where(i => !p.Contains(i));`

Comment: @Fabio: Isn't this another query which OP doesn't want?

Comment: @FabioLuz that's another iteration

Comment: Do you want *all* the items that aren't included in that query? That's pretty simple -- `var p = option.GetType().GetProperties()`

Comment: p contains a set of the list option. I want all the rest of the elements except the items in set p without executin a second iteration.

Comment: How about using `GroupBy` and using the groups afterwards?

Comment: `var p = option.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t != typeof(bool));` Would get all options that aren't in your example code.

Comment: @MichaelMcPherson that would cause another iteration over the list. Check out the answer, it's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Chris Yeah. It would. If you want two sets out of one set, you're going to have to examine the first set twice.

Comment: Not really. You could examine the whole set just once and create 2 separate sets from the examination @MichaelMcPherson

Comment: So what's your aversion to doing that?

Comment: @MichaelMcPherson 
If by 'that' you mean examining the list twice instead of once : it's bad for my soul.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var p = option.GetType().GetProperties().ToLookup(t => t.PropertyType == typeof(bool));

var bools = p[true];

var notBools = p[false];
```

`.ToLookup()` is used to partition an IEnumerable based on a key function. In this case, it will return an Lookup which will have at most 2 items in it. Items in the Lookup can be accessed using a key similar to an IDictionary.

`.ToLookup()` is evaluated immediately and is an O(n) operation and accessing a partition in the resulting Lookup is an O(1) operation.

Lookup is very similar to a Dictionary and have similar generic parameters (a Key type and a Value type). However, where Dictionary maps a key to a single value, Lookup maps a key to an set of values. Lookup can be implemented as `IDictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>`

`.GroupBy()` could also be used. But it is different from `.ToLookup()` in that GroupBy is lazy evaluated and could possibly be enumerated multiple times. `.ToLookup()` is evaluated immediately and the work is only done once.

Comment: Great , I guess it's a good time for me to get familiat wit ToLookup :P

Comment: But isn't under the hood there are 2 queries: one for `bools` and one for `notBools`? Usage is pretty though.

Comment: No, there is not two queries, only one. ToLookup() iterates over the list once and based on the evaluation of the expression, adds the current item to either the true list or false list. ToLookup() executes immediately, just like ToList().

Comment: Haven't seen this answer before i posted mine. However, note that `t == typeof(bool)` never is true because a PropertyInfo is never a bool.

Comment: I see now. `ToLookup()` will execute query over `GetProperties()` once and result will be stored in some structure `p` (lookup). Then `p[true]` and `p[false]` only does query over that new structure, which obviously avoid iterating over `option.GetType().GetProperties()` again and is much more efficient. New day - something new to learn.

Comment: @TimSchmelter is correct about PropertyInfo never being equal to the bool Type. I left the answer as is, since it matches the question.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get something that you don't ask for. So if you exlude all but `bool` you can't expect to get them later. You need to ask for them.

For what it's worth, if you need both, the one you want and all other in a single query you could `GroupBy` this condition or use `ToLookup` which i would prefer:

```
var isboolOrNotLookup =  option.GetType().GetProperties()
    .ToLookup(t => t.PropertyType == typeof(bool)); // use PropertyType instead
```

Now you can use this lookup for further processing. For example, if you want a collection of all properties which are bool:

```
List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> boolTypes = isboolOrNotLookup[true].ToList();
```

or just the count:

```
int boolCount = isboolOrNotLookup[true].Count();
```

So if you want to process all which are not `bool`:

```
foreach(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo prop in isboolOrNotLookup[false])
{

}
```

Comment: Yeah, familiarity with ToLookUp was the key part in solving this with LINQ.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you could go for `source.Except(p)`, but it would reiterate the list and perform a lot of comparisons.

I'd say - write an extension method that does it using `foreach`, basically splitting the list into two destinations. Or something like this.

How about:

```
public class UnzipResult<T>{
    private readonly IEnumearator<T> _enumerator;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _filter;

    private readonly Queue<T> _nonMatching = new Queue<T>();
    private readonly Queue<T> _matching = new Queue<T>();

    public IEnumerable<T> Matching {get{
        if(_matching.Count > 0)
            yield return _matching.Dequeue();
        else {
            while(_enumerator.MoveNext()){
            if(_filter(_enumerator.Current))
                yield return _enumerator.Current;
            else 
                _nonMatching.Enqueue(_enumerator.Current);
            }
            yield break;
        }
    }}

    public IEnumerable<T> Rest {get{
        if(_matching.Count > 0)
            yield return _nonMatching.Dequeue();
        else {
            while(_enumerator.MoveNext()){
            if(!_filter(_enumerator.Current))
                yield return _enumerator.Current;
            else 
                _matching.Enqueue(_enumerator.Current);
            }
            yield break;
        }
    }}

    public UnzipResult(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter){
        _enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        _filter = filter;
    }
}

public static UnzipResult<T> Unzip(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,bool> filter){
    return new UnzipResult(source, filter);
}
```

It's written in notepad, so probably doesn't compile, but my idea is: whatever collection you enumerate (matching or non-matching), you only enumerate the source once. And it should work fairly well with those pesky infinite collections (think `yield return random.Next()`), unless all elements do/don't fulfil `filter`.